# How to insert chid to tag with VBScript?

Tags: xml, vbscript, nodes

I'm trying to create a XML file with the following code.

```vb
Set Client = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Client") 
Set Client_ID = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Client_ID")
Client_ID.AppendChild kunden  
Set name = xmlDoc.CreateElement("GivenName")  
Client_ID.SelectNodes("//@Client//Client_ID")
Set surnamename = xmlDoc.CreateElement("surname")
Client_ID.AppendChild name
Client_ID.AppendChild surname
```

That is what I'm getting:

```xml
<ROOT>
  <Info>
    <Number>atl-ws-001</Number>
    <Date>04.12.2017</Date>
  </Info>
  <Test>
    <Client>
      <Client_ID/>
      <GiveName/>
      <SURNAME/>
    </Client>
  </Test>
</ROOT>
```

and that what I'm trying to get the XML file like this one:

```xml
<ROOT>
  <Info>
    <Number>atl-ws-001</Number>
    <Date>04.12.2017</Date>
  </Info>
  <Test>
    <Client>
      <Client_ID>
        <GivenName/>
        <surname/>
      </Client_ID>
    </Client>
  </Test>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: The code you posted can't possibly give you the result you say you're getting. Please make sure to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the methods by the book. Demo:

```
Option Explicit

Dim o : Set o = CreateObject("msxml2.domdocument")
o.loadXml "<a><b></b></a>"
Dim Client : Set Client = o.createElement("Client")
Dim Client_ID : Set Client_ID = o.createElement("Client_ID")
Client_ID.appendChild o.createElement("GivenName")
Client_ID.appendChild o.createElement("SurName")
Client.appendChild Client_ID
o.SelectSingleNode("/a/b").appendChild Client
WScript.Echo o.xml
```

output:

```
cscript 47637542.vbs
<a><b><Client><Client_ID><GivenName/><SurName/></Client_ID></Client></b></a>
```

(Using XPATH "//" is nearly always a bad idea)

Comment: That 's what  i needed, Thank you